# File editing class

Tags: python, object-oriented, file, classes

I was making this file editing class (writing to a file, reading a file etc.) in Python and was just looking for any feedback.

Note: I've been thinking about removing the `file_name` property and requiring file name on each method call.

```
import os

class EditFile:

    """
    format: <object_name> = EditFile(<file_name>)
    """

    # constructor
    def __init__(self, file_name):
        self.file_name = file_name  # can be changed at any time

    # string version
    def __repr__(self):
        return "<object_name> = EditFile(<file_name>)"

    # methods
    def write(self, text):  # writes text in a file
        try:
            f = open(self.file_name, "w")  # opens file & selects WRITE mode also creates a new file if it doesnt exist
            f.write(str(text))

        finally:
            f.close()

    def append(self, text):  # appends text to a file
        try:
            f = open(self.file_name, "a")  # opens file & selects APPEND mode
            f.write(text)

        finally:
            f.close()

    @property
    def read(self):  # reads the file
        try:
            f = open(self.file_name, "r")  # opens file & selects READ mode
            content = f.read()  # saves content of the file into content variable

        finally:
            f.close()

        return content  # returns content of the file

    def read_bytes(self, number_of_bytes = 0):  # reads certain amount of bytes
        try:
            int(number_of_bytes)

            if number_of_bytes == 0:  # checks if its default
                f = open(self.file_name, "rb")
                content = f.read()

                return content

            elif number_of_bytes >= 1:  # checks if number of bytes is a valid number
                f = open(self.file_name, "rb")
                content = f.read(number_of_bytes)

                return content

            else:
                return "error"  # returns "error" if input is invalid

        except ValueError:
            return "value error"

        finally:
            f.close()

    def write_bytes(self, text):  # writes in bytes
        try:
            f = open(self.file_name, "wb")  # selects WRITE BYTES mode
            f.write(str(text))

        finally:
            f.close()

    @property
    def clear(self):  # clears a file
        try:
            f = open(self.file_name, "w")  # opens file and selects WRITE mode
            f.write("")  # sets file content to none

        finally:
            f.close()

    @property
    def delete(self):  # deletes current file
        try:
            os.remove(self.file_name)  # tries to delete file

        except OSError:
            return "error"  # returns "error" if an error occurs (eg file doesnt exist)

# example program using most of the methods
file = EditFile("editme.txt")

file.write(str(input("Text:\n")))
print(file.read)
file.clear
file.delete

# editing file: editme2.txt
file.file_name = "editme2.txt"
file.write(str(input("Text:\n")))
print(file.read_bytes(5))
file.delete
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
"<object_name> = EditFile(<file_name>)"
```

is not a particularly useful `__repr__`. Note the guidance in [the data model documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__):

> If at all possible, this should look like a valid Python expression
>   that could be used to recreate an object with the same value (given an
>   appropriate environment). If this is not possible, a string of the
>   form `<...some useful description...>` should be returned.

In this case, that could be:

```
"EditFile({!r})".format(self.file_name)
```

---

For all of your file access, you should use the context manager provided by `open`, e.g.:

```
@property
def read(self):  # reads the file
    with open(self.file_name) as f:
        return f.read()
```

This will handle closing the file for you after the method ends.

---

It seems weird that `read` is a property but `read_bytes` is a method - as the latter requires an argument, and both names describe *actions*, perhaps they should both be methods? If you still wanted the property then a name describing a *thing*, like `content`, would be better for it.

---

I would generally expect attribute access not to change state, so it seems even weirder for `clear` and `delete`, again *actions* rather than *things*, to be properties. Just make them methods. Also the fact that they return either `None` (if successful) or a string (if there was an error) is a really strange interface for a consumer of the class to deal with.

---

Your error handling in general is a bit odd. Why take a useful exception and squash it down to a meaningless string? You're giving the users of your class *less information*. If you can't add to them or usefully handle them, let the errors continue through your code to the caller. And rather than:

```
return "error"  # returns "error" if input is invalid
```

raise an error with a useful message yourself, in this case e.g.:

```
raise ValueError("cannot read a negative number of bytes")
```

This actually *tells the user something useful*.

Also note that:

```
int(number_of_bytes)
```

although it checks that `number_of_bytes` *could be* made an integer, doesn't actually change what's assigned to the name; if it was `'1'`, for example, weird things will happen next. Instead, *use the result*:

```
number_of_bytes = int(number_of_bytes)
```

---

Rather than using simple comments to describe your methods, use [docstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/):

```
def write_bytes(self, text):
    """Writes in bytes."""
    ...
```

Unlike comments these can be used by other tools, e.g. the built-in `help` function, to make that information available in other forms.

---

```
self.file_name = file_name  # can be changed at any time
```

Here *is* a good use for a `@property`; you could use it to make the filename read-only by convention:

```
self._file_name = file_name
```

The leading underscore indicates that this should be considered private, then you can write a getter:

```
@property
def file_name(self):
    return self.file_name
```

Your other idea, requiring the filename every time a method is called, would turn this into a class without *any* instance state, in which case it probably shouldn't be a class at all.